# Form not submitting any params

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, hotwire-rails

I'm iterating through a collection of `User.permissions`. The form fields are disabled because I don't want persisted `Permission` objects to be modified, but I want to be able to submit the form to the `edit_user_path` where I capture the params and use them to build a new `Permission` (some sort of copy/paste functionality).

However, when I submit the form, nothing is being sent as params. The server logs show:

```
Started GET "/users/1/edit?commit=Save+"
```

Don't know if it's relevant, but the `turbo_method: :get` also doesn't seem be picked up, as it is the `method: :get` what  actually determines if the form makes a `GET` or `POST` request when submitted.

Here's the form:

```
<% @user.permissions.where.not(id: nil).each do |permission| %>
    <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
      <%= form_with(url: edit_user_path(@user), method: :get, data: { turbo_frame: :new_permission_form, turbo_method: :get }) do |f| %>
        <div class="flex flex-row items-center" id=<%= "permission_#{permission.id}" %>>

          <div class="flex flex-row mb-5 items-end">
            <div class="me-3 flex flex-col">
              <%= f.select :survey_type_id,
                  SurveyType.all.pluck(:description, :id),
                  {{selected: permission.survey_type_id},},
                  class: 'form-select mt-1.5 w-full rounded-lg border',
                  disabled: true
              %>

            </div>

            <div class="me-3 flex flex-col">
              <%= f.select :year,
                Survey.all.pluck(:year).uniq,
                {{selected: permission.year},},
                class: 'form-select mt-1.5 w-full rounded-lg border',
                disabled: true
              %>

              <%= f.submit %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

*UsersController:*

```
  def edit
    @permission = @user.permissions.build(permission_params)
  end
```